# Numpy: Index 3d array by z-index array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Say I have an array

```
a = np.zeros((3, 3, 3))
```

and a z-index array

```
z = np.random.randint(0, 3, (3, 3))
```

say z is

```
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
```

Now I want to select the values of `a` with coordinates (starting at top left of `z` and traversing the array row-wise. Column-wise would be fine too.) (0, 0, **1**), (0, 1, **0**), (0, 2, **2**), ... . The bold values are from the `z` array.

Comment: is `a` supposed to be a 3d array?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.arange(3*3*3).reshape(3,3,3)
z = np.array([[1, 0, 2],
       [2, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]])
i = np.arange(a.shape[0]).repeat(a.shape[0]).reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[1])
j = i.T
#Should do the same as this. possible more efficient, did not test.
#i, j = np.indices(a[...,0].shape)
print a[i,j,z]
```

Comment: Nope. If I use zeros and then `a[i,j,z] = 1`, `a[0, 0 ,0]` is `1` but should be `0`.

Comment: It works if `i` is `array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]])` and `j` is `i.T`.